# All points umbillical $\iff$ Surface is either contained in a sphere or in a plane.

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

We assume $S$ connected and orientable surface.

**Proof:** Let $k_1=k_2=:\kappa$    be principal curvatures.
From $\kappa(p) I(\partial_u,\partial_u)=-II(\partial_u,\partial_u)$ we see that $\kappa$ is differentiable since $I(\partial_u,\partial_u),II(\partial_u,\partial_u)$ are.
Furthermore $$N_{*p}(\partial_u)=\kappa(p)\partial_u$$
$$N_{*p}(\partial_v)=\kappa(p)\partial_v$$

Differentiating both equations with respect to $v$ and $u$ as in Do Carmo book we get:
$$\partial_v N_{*p}(\partial_u)=\partial_v(\kappa(p)\partial_u)=\partial_v(\kappa(p))\partial_u+\kappa(p)\partial_v\partial_u$$
$$\partial_u N_{*p}(\partial_v)=\partial_u(\kappa(p)\partial_v)=\partial_u(\kappa(p))\partial_v+\kappa(p)\partial_u\partial_v$$
Now subtracting:
$$ \partial_v N_{*p}(\partial_u)-\partial_u N_{*p}(\partial_v)=\partial_v(\kappa(p))\partial_u+\kappa(p)\partial_v\partial_u - \partial_u(\kappa(p)) \partial_v-\kappa(p)\partial_u\partial_v$$
Then by Schwarz's Theorem:
$$ \partial_v N_{*p}(\partial_u)-\partial_u N_{*p}(\partial_v)=\partial_v(\kappa(p))\partial_u- \partial_u(\kappa(p)) \partial_v$$
And here I'm stuck.
Why is left side zero?